# Is there a way to sum the contents of a dictionary embedded in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I am new to python and coding in general but I am trying to make one data structure from a set of data while also using that data structure to sum the mol fractions in that data.

```
C2H5ONO = {'species': 'ethyl_nitrite', 'molfrac': 90}
C2H50= {'species': 'hydroxyethyl', 'molfrac': 1}
NO = {'species': 'nitrogen_monoxide', 'molfrac': 1}
CH3 = {'species': 'methyl_radical', 'molfrac': 0.5}
CH2O = {'species': 'formaldehyde', 'molfrac': 0.5}
CH3CHO = {'species': 'acetaldehyde', 'molfrac': 1}
HNO = {'species': 'nitroxyl', 'molfrac': 0.5}
C2H5OH = {'species': 'ethanol', 'molfrac': 1}
NOH = {'species': 'nitrogen_hydroxide', 'molfrac': 0.5}
N2O = {'species': 'nitric_oxide', 'molfrac': 1}
H2O = {'species': 'water', 'molfrac': 1}
CH3NO = {'species': 'formamide', 'molfrac': 1}
CH2_NOH = {'species': 'formaldoxime', 'molfrac': 0.5}
HCN = {'species': 'hydrogen_cyanide', 'molfrac': 0.5}

data = {'C2H5ONO': C2H5ONO, 'C2H50': C2H50, 'NO': NO, 'CH3': CH3, 'CH2O': CH2O,
        'CH3CHO': CH3CHO, 'HNO': HNO, 'C2H5OH': C2H5OH, 'NOH': NOH, 'N2O': N2O,
        'H2O': H2O, 'CH3NO': CH3NO, 'CH2_NOH': CH2_NOH, 'HCN': HCN }
```

this is what I have right now and I was trying to use a for loop to sum it all but have had no Luck because molfrac isn't defined within data, only within each smaller dictionary. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: It would be great if you could show us how you've attempted to solve this so far.

Comment: something like  `sum(v['molfrac'] for v in data.values())`?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Define you data structure as a dict of dicts, then iterate over its keys and sum up the corresponding values of the inner dicts. Note that in the data structure definition, I avoided the extra intermediate variables that you showed in all caps. Below is an example with just 3 entries:

```
mol_frcs = {
    'C2H5ONO': {'species': 'ethyl_nitrite', 'molfrac': 90},
    'C2H50': {'species': 'hydroxyethyl', 'molfrac': 1},
    'NO': {'species': 'nitrogen_monoxide', 'molfrac': 1},
}

sum_mol_frcs = sum(mol_frcs[k]['molfrac'] for k in mol_frcs)
print(sum_mol_frcs)
# 92
```

Comment: `for k in some_dict` already iterates through the keys, there's no need to explicitly iterate over `dict.keys()`.

Comment: @blorgon Thank you for the comment, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a dictionary of dictionaries, all you need to do is iterate through the outer dictionary, accumulating the `molfrac`.

```py
mol_frac_sum = 0
for _, mol in data.items():
    mol_frac_sum += mol["molfrac"]
```

The `data.items()` gives key-value tuples from the `data` dictionary. The `_, mol` is unpacking that tuple into `_` (for the string key for each molecule, which we don't care about), and `mol` which is the individual inner dictionary. Then you just access each inner dictionary's `"molfrac"` value and add it to your accumulator.

You should read up on the documentation for Python's `dict`, and possible also the accumulator pattern (a general programming pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pythonic way to get it done.

```
sum([v['molfrac'] for v in data.values()])
```

Comment: OP is new to coding, I think it's more important to teach them the fundamentals of the accumulator pattern before throwing comprehensions at them. Also, you don't need to sum over a list comprehension, you can pass a generator directly into `sum()`. Creating a list comprehension first puts it into memory, and is slower as a result.